# RabbitMQ: Routing key + queue + delay

Tags: java, queue, rabbitmq, consumer, producer

I have a Producer as follows:

```
public class MyProducer {

private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "messages";

public static void main(String[] argv)
              throws java.io.IOException {

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "direct");

    String color1 = "red"
    String message1 = "message1"

    String color2 = "blue"
    String message2 = "message2"

    channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, color1, null, message1);
    channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, color2, null, message2);

    channel.close();
    connection.close();
}
}
```

and also a consumer:

```
public class MyConsumer {

private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "messages";

public static void main(String[] argv)
              throws java.io.IOException,
              java.lang.InterruptedException {

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "direct");
    String queueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();


    channel.queueBind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, "color1");
    channel.queueBind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, "color2");


    QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
    channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);

}
```

}

My questions are now:

1. Do I have now only one queue named "queuName" or do I have two queues named "color1" and "color2"?
2. I don't want to consume the messages immediatly. So what I want is to set a delay for each queue "color1" and "color2". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question-1) Do I have now only one queue named "queuName" or do I have two queues named "color1" and "color2"?

Answer : You have to must go through tutorial

https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

base on that you decide how you want to create queue and which exchange types[direct, topic, headers and fanout] match to your requirement or sometime its happen no need to exchange  ..so first see tutorial and then base on your requirement decide.

Question-2)I don't want to consume the messages immediately. So what I want is to set a delay for each queue "color1" and "color2". How can I achieve this?

Answer: for that you have to write your own logic which delay the consumer to find message from rabbit, you can go through thread also.

Enjoy Rabbit programming :)

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, the answer is "neither."  Your code shows you declaring a randomly-named queue and assigning whatever the server names it to the variable `queueName`:

> String queueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();

Your uses of `"color1"` and `"color2"` are as binding keys (see [this page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html)) on the random queue you created.  If the intent is to declare a queue of a specific name, I believe that would need to be passed in as an argument to the `queueDeclare` function (though admittedly I am unfamiliar with this particular library).

For your second question, if you don't want to consume messages immediately, then you don't have to. Instead, initiate the consumer when you want to. Nobody is forcing you to put that in your program directly beneath the `queueDeclare` method. I cannot list specific ways to achieve this as there are probably as many as you can think of.